# Bootstrap Grid arrangement on responsive view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Is it possible to do this?

I have 3 columns in a row. The first column has 2 nested row - top and bottom.
Is it possible to have the bottom row of the first column to be at the fourth position is the mobile view?

Here is my code:
http://www.bootply.com/yhhFaWRjC6
Edit:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12" style="background-color:#ccc;height:100%; padding:0px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 " style="height:180px;background-color:#d33;">one</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 " style="height:180px;background-color:#edd;">four</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12" style="height:360px;background-color:#e42;">two</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12" style="height:360px;background-color:#444;color:#fff;">three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it the sequence to be:
- one
- two
- three
- four
In mobile

Comment: Your link does not currently work (gives 'Application error'). Could you add some more information to your question? I'm particularly confused about what is the 'fourth position'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first column to be less in height than both the second and third column I'm afraid you can only achieve this by:

1. Duplicating the content of the fourth column and showing/hiding it based on the grid size (e.g. `xs`). I'll show an example of this below.
2. Using JavaScript to move the content of the fourth column when the grid size changes. I have a small prototype of a jQuery plugin to facilitate this at https://github.com/ckuijjer/jquery-breakpointspy
3. Create your own grid system using flexbox. This might be an option if you don't have to support IE9 or lower.

I've implemented the first option below, and made some additional changes:

- I've moved the inline styling into classes named `.one`, `.two`, `.three` and `.four` to make the code a little bit more clean.
- I've started with the mobile layout and gave all classes `col-xs-12`. This makes a column take up 12 columns from the size `xs` onwards.

  ```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 one">one</div>
      ...
      <div class="col-xs-12 four">four</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- As we want to have each column take up a fourth of the container, I've added `col-md-4` to each of the columns. Each column now looks like e.g. `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 one">`. There is no need to add `col-lg-4` nor `col-sm-12`.
- Showing a column only on a specific grid size can be done by e.g. `visible-xs-block`. As we want the fourth column to only be visible on `xs` and `sm` I've changed the html into `<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs-block visible-sm-block four">four</div>`. Notice that I've dropped the `col-md-4` as there is no need for that anymore.
- To put the fourth column below the first column when the screen is `md` or `lg` the first column is changed into a nested grid. I've opted not to use a second `.row` as having more than 12 columns will make the next column drop anyway and used `.col-xs-12` as I always want a column to have a bootstrap grid class on it, regardless of the screen size. I could've used `visible-md-block` and `visible-lg-block` to make it show on `md` and `lg` only, but for fun I've used its opposite, `hidden-xs` and `hidden-sm`.

  ```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 one">one</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm four">four</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

See the entire code below:

```css
.one {
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #d33;
}
.two {
  height: 360px;
  background-color: #e42;
}
.three {
  height: 360px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
.four {
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #edd;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 one">one</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm four">four</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 two">two</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 three">three</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs-block visible-sm-block four">four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```